# Get content from post using AJAX in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to get content from post via AJAX in Wordpress

Here is the js part

```
$("a.ajaxed").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    doAjaxRequest();
});
function doAjaxRequest(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
        data: ({action : 'ajaxify',
            post_id: $(this).attr('id')
            }),
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data.post_title);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the functions.php part

```
function ajaxify() {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $post_data = get_post($post_id);
    echo json_encode($post_data);
}
```

console.log(data.post_title) always shows undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post_id was undefined

```
$("a.ajaxed").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();     
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
        data: ({
            action : 'ajaxify',
            post_id: $(this).parent().attr("id")
            }),
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```